# How do I solve the problem of eclipse automatically converting; to an unwanted method on input?

Tags: java, eclipse

https://youtu.be/_6l6NmDvVsg

As you can see in the video, if you type contentPane.repaint() and then type ;, repaint automatically changes to getIgnoreRepaint(). I am wondering how to solve this problem.

source is

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;


class RandomThread extends Thread{
    Container contentPane;
    boolean flag = false;
    public RandomThread(Container contentPane) {
        this.contentPane = contentPane;
    }

    void finish() {
        flag = true;
    }

    public void run()
    {
        while(true)
        {
            int x = ((int)(Math.random()*contentPane.getWidth()));
            int y = ((int)(Math.random()*contentPane.getHeight()));
            JLabel label = new JLabel("Java");
            label.setSize(80,30);
            label.setLocation(x, y);
            contentPane.add(label);
            contentPane.getIgnoreRepaint(); // why this happen?
            try {
                Thread.sleep(300);
                if(flag == true) {
                    contentPane.removeAll();
                    label = new JLabel("finish");
                    label.setSize(80, 30);
                    label.setLocation(100, 100);
                    label.setForeground(Color.red);
                    contentPane.add(label);
                    contentPane.getIgnoreRepaint();  //same problem
                    return;
                }
            }
            catch(InterruptedException e) { return; }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like the content-assist proposals are appearing in alphabetic order rather than relevance.

You can change this order in *Window>Preferences*, on the page *Java>Editor>Content Assist*.

In the section ***Sorting and Filtering***, change ***Sort proposals*** from *alphabetically* to ***by relevance***.

**EDIT**

In addition, in the next preference page *Java>Editor>Content Assist>Advanced*, in the top list, turn on ***Java proposals***.

Comment: First, there is no sorting and filtering in the advanced section.
Second, it is already set by by relevance.
https://imgur.com/xMZZG94

Comment: @decussat - Try the additional step in the edit above.